# usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed MSI | ubuntu 16.04 fancontrol

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I've installed `lm-sensors`, but when I run `pwmconfig` command as root, it throws an error:

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

My laptop is an MSI Gs63VR Stealth Pro core Intel i7 CPU

Thank you!

Comment: This question should probably be moved to [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), another site on the StackExchange network dedicated to Ubuntu questions. You'll get better answers there.

Answer (score 6):

A simple search for the error message yielded several hits on Google. All of the top hits are from before this question was posted.

[This guide on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/46135/52781) may be helpful, or [this one](https://iandw.net/2014/10/12/fancontrol-under-ubuntu-14-04-resolving-usrsbinpwmconfig-there-are-no-pwm-capable-sensor-modules-installed/).

Likely the issue you're having can be solved with a linux kernel option. Add this to your Grub command-line: `acpi_enforce_resources=lax`

```
sudo sed -E -i 's/(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=.+)"$/\1 acpi_enforce_resources=lax"/' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

then reboot.

Comment: yes, this is a proposal for a fix of the problem, but as it is stated in a lot of places with the same question - it do not solve the problem everywhere, I can confirm that this line into grub and update-grub give me the same results as stated into the question above.

Comment: @Borislav have you run `sensors-detect`? What distribution? Have you followed any guides?

Comment: Yes, I have followed a lot of guides, most of them leading to a moment when you enable a few modules using sensor-detect, but luckily sensor detect enables only one module coretemp. So because of this I keep receiving the same error, also sensors returns only temperatures, not voltage and fanspeeds. elementaryOS Hera, based on Ubuntu 18.04, hp Pavilion power pc, same result I have on Ubuntu 18.04...

Comment: Running sensors-detect I have one line `Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE...               Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x8987` and Googling a lot I did not found an option to load the correct module.

Comment: @Borislav you ran `sensors-detect` as root? You should consider posting a new question on AskUbuntu with everything you have tried. I have seen people discussing sensors working on your hardware ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183741/pwm-config-detects-fan-but-doesnt-influence-it-at-all)) so it should be possible.

Comment: Yes, I'm running it with `sudo`, now I have just tried with `sudo su` first also and the resuts are the same. But I have two fans, compared to the results on the link above, but you are right - probably it will be better to ask a new question here

Comment: @Borislav sorry I couldn't be of more help! Link your question here if you end up creating one.

Comment: No worries, thank you for putting your attention to my problem, but I lost hope. I have read probably more than 20 different forum posts on russian, polish, german websites, all with the same results like mine about ITE IT8987D and there is no any usefull information about drivers, no success confirmed. I have tried with modprobe all ntlXXXX drivers I have into my system, also stuff like `modprobe it87 force_id=0x8987` with no positive result. Thanks again, happy hollidays, if I change my mind, I will link my question here.

Comment: I did this and it did not fix the error message posted by Takeshi.

Comment: @theerrormagnet ok. This question was posted by a new user who hadn't seem to have done the basic minimum of using a search engine to try to answer the question themselves. Why not post a new question on Super User or Server Fault? Include details, since comments and questions to the effect of "it didn't work/it's broken" are unlikely to produce the answer you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

On my MSI GF76 Katana 11SC-483X there are no pwm-capable sensors detected in linux.
This tool helped me to control fans: https://github.com/dmitry-s93/MControlCenter#installation-from-the-archive

Added this tool to Startup Applications on my Ubuntu 22.04 (used custom curve) - it works like a charm!
It works much better than MSI Control Center on windows. May be I'm doing something wrong but my manual tests for windows MSI Control Center have bad results (custom curve) - fans sometimes speed up, sometimes not.